# Mostrar diagonal de una matriz en un array en C#

Tags: c#, array, matrices, array-bidimensional

estoy aqui por primera vez ya que me encuentro trabado a la hora de resolver un ejercicio que se me pide en un trabajo práctico de la facultad. Estoy comenzando en la programación y el lenguaje utilizado es C#.

Aclaro que no estoy en busca aqui colocar mis consignas y que alguien mas lo resuelva, llego aqui porque doy vueltas y vueltas y no ajusto el código a lo que la consigna me pide.

Sin mas, la consigna dice, mostrar en pantalla la creacion de una matriz de 6x6 con numeros aleatorios entre 2 y 8, a su vez mostrar debajo un array con la diagonal de dicha matriz.

Lo tengo todo hecho, lo que pasa es que la muestra del array, me imprime el mismo valor 6 veces. Entiendo que es un error de logica mia, pero no logro visualizar cual y donde, ya que intente de todas maneras y me pasa que me lo muestra asi o directamente no lo muestra.

Mi codigo es:

```
int[,] mat = new int[6, 6];
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int fil = 0; fil < 6; fil++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
                {
                    mat[fil, col] = rnd.Next(2, 9);
                    Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Diagonal");
            for (int fil = 0; fil < 6; fil++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
                {
                    if (fil == col)
                    {
                        for (int ar = 0; ar < 6; ar++)
                        {
                            int[] array = new int[6];
                            array[ar] = mat[fil, col];
                            Console.Write(array[ar] + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta volviendo a recorrer con un `for` cuando no es necesario, porque ya te paraste en la fila y columna indicada. Te quite el `for` de tu codigo y funciona.

```
        int[,] mat = new int[6, 6];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int fil = 0; fil < 6; fil++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
            {
                mat[fil, col] = rnd.Next(2, 9);
                Console.Write(mat[fil, col] + " ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Diagonal");
        for (int fil = 0; fil < 6; fil++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
            {
                if (fil == col)
                {
                        int[] array = new int[6];
                        array[fil] = mat[fil, col];
                        Console.Write(array[fil] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

      Resultado: 
      4 5 5 3 7 3
      7 6 8 8 4 5
      7 3 4 2 6 6
      7 6 6 7 5 6
      4 3 4 3 8 8
      7 5 3 2 3 6
      Diagonal
      4 6 4 7 8 6
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, entiendo lo de los for, que estaba repitiendo. Sabia porque me lo mostraba tantas veces, pero no estaba consiguiendo anular eso. Intente de otras maneras pero como digo, o me mostraba nada y me daba error, o solo 1 fila.

Sirvio mucho, de nuevo gracias. Que tengas buenas noches

Comment: @RainDMT, marcala como aceptada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

según lo que comentaste necesitas que te den un empujón nada más.

Un concepto que esta bueno para mirar es el [Big-O](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cota_superior_asint%C3%B3tica). Cuando recorriste la diagonal hiciste 3 for anidados. Eso te da un costo de computo del tipo O³.

Como sabes que la matriz es cuadrada podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    Console.write(mat[i,i] + "\t")// mostrar celda de la matriz
}
```

Esta forma de encaralo tiene un costo de O¹